# Call a C++ function from a C++ library in Linux

Tags: c++

I want to call a function from C++ library on linux. I have a shared object of that library.
I want to call method getAge() that return an int from ydmg library.

Following is the code that I have written:

testydmg.cpp

```
#include "ydmg/bd.h"
#include "yut/hash.h"
#include "dlfcn.h"

extern "C" int getAge();

class testydmg{
   public:
        testydmg::testydmg(const yutHash& user){

        }
         testydmg::testydmg(){

        }

         testydmg::~testydmg(){

        }


        int testydmg::getFunction(){
                void *handle;
                int (*voidfnc)();
                handle = dlopen("ydmg.so",RTLD_LAZY);
                if(handle == NULL){
                        printf("error in opening ydmg lib");
                } else {
                        voidfnc = (int (*)())dlsym(handle, "getAge");
                        (*voidfnc)();
                        printf("class loaded");
                }
                ydmgBd obj;
                obj.getAge();
                printf("Inside getFunction()...");
                dlclose(handle);

        }
};
```

I compile and link the code as below:

> gcc -fPIC -shared -l stdc++ -I/home/y/libexec64/jdk1.6.0/include -I/home/y/libexec64/jdk1.6.0/include/linux -I/home/y/include testydmg.cpp -o libTestYdmg.so libydmg.so

Then I check for the method in the new shared object i.e. libTestYdmg.so

> nm -C libTestYdmg.so | egrep getAge
>   I get nothing by running the above command.

Does it mean that it did not get the method getAge() from the library.
Could you please correct where I am going wrong ?

Comment: I see no library there? The getAge remains a unresolved/deferred symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `ydmgDB::getAge()` but you are asking to the library for `getAge()`. This is not correct, just simply create a `ydmgDB`object and invoke it's method `getAge()` without loading the library that is linked with your compile command line.

You don't need to `dlopen` the library.

Besides, `getAge` is not really included in `libTestYdmg.so`. You must look for it in `libydmg.so` using:

```
nm -C libydmg.so | grep getAge
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in actually using dlopen in C++ code, take a look at the
[C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html), which includes example code and some possibly important
warnings.